# How do I write a SQL Query that Displays a List assigned only to only the logged in User?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have a set of Users with different role types Marketer , Admin, General Manager. When a customer account is registered , there is a column that gets the name of the Marketer assigned to the Customer . I have created a @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationship between Users and Customers. When User type Marketer logs in to the software , I want **the marketer to see only customers registered to the logged in Marketer name**. It seems complicated because first I need to get the logged in Marketer details using the username then get the first and last name then display customer list assigned to the name.

This is the **Customer entity**

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer","handler"})
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8348682056500740593L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
    
    private String gender;
    private String Address; 
    private String maritalStatus;
    private String category;
    private String motherMaidenName;
    private String idType;
    private String  idNumber;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date registrationDate;
    
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, 
     fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name="marketer_id") 
    private User marketer ;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Investment.class)
    private List <Investment> investment;
```

This is the **User Entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String firstName ;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String Gender; 
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private String branch;
    
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
    name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>();
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;
    
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="marketer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Customer.class)
    private List <Customer> customer;
```

This is the **User Repository** that contains a FindByUsername method that's being used by JWT authentication manager

```
@Repository
public interface UserAccountRepository extends JpaRepository <User, Long>  {
    
     Optional<User> findById(Long id);

     User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**UPDATED :** I got empty response from the Query , what could I be doing wrong ? This is the updated Customer controller class

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000"})
@RestController
public class CustomerController {

@Autowired
CustomerAccountService customerRepo;

@Autowired
UserAccountService  userRepo;

 @GetMapping(value="marketers/customers")
         public List<Customer> getLlistByMarketerName(){
         Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();     
         User loggedInUser =userRepo.findByUserName(authentication.getName());
         System.out.println("logged in user:"+ loggedInUser);
         return customerRepo.findByMarketer(loggedInUser);
```

I printed the loggedInUser variable out but it display null.

Answer (score 0):

Your CustomerRepository should handle this easily:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
  List<Customer> findByMarketer(User marketer);
}
```

If you want to be more explicit and show the query:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
  @Query("select customer from Customer customer join customer.marketer marketer where marketer = :marketer")
  List<Customer> findByMarketer(User marketer);
}
```

The User (marketer) being passed is the current user obtained from the UserAccountRepository.

Comment: What I got is null or empty response